# How dose [self] work on Swift ? It work like [unowned self] or strong reference

Tags: swift, self, self-reference

I know [weak self] and [unowned self] but I don't know [self].

How dose it work ?

**[self] = [unowned self]**
or
**[self] = strong reference**

Answer (score 0):

Capturing a variable through a capture clause:

```
var closure = { [x] in x.doSomething() }
```

will create a strong capture of the value that x is referencing to at the time the closure is *created*. See example at the end.

If you do not use the capture clause like in

```
var closure = { x.doSomething() }
```

this will create a strong reference to the value that x is referencing to at the time the closure is *executed*.

That being said, capturing `[self]` creates a strong reference, but is completely unnecessary unless you expect that `self` is changing at some point in time (which would be quite unusual).

---

### Example

```
class ValueClass {
    var value:String
    
    init (_ v:String)   { value = v }
    
    func info()         { print("\(value)") }
    deinit              { print ("deinit: \(value)") }
}

if (1==1) {
    print (">> No capture clause")
    var a:ValueClass? = ValueClass("a")
    let closure = { a != nil ? a!.info() : print("a is nil") }
    a = ValueClass("changed a")     // "deinit: a"
    closure()   // "a is nil"
    print ("<< done")
}// "deinit: changed a"

print ("------------------------------")

if (1==1) {
    print (">> strong capture clause")
    var b:ValueClass? = ValueClass("b")
    let closure = { [b] in b != nil ? b!.info() : print("b is nil") }
    b = ValueClass("changed b")
    closure()                   // "b"
    print ("<< done")
}                               // "deinit: b"; "deinit: changed b"

print ("------------------------------")

if (1==1) {
    print (">> weak capture clause")
    var c:ValueClass? = ValueClass("c")
    let closure = { [weak c] in c != nil ? c!.info() : print("c is nil") }
    c = ValueClass("changed c")     // "deinit: c"
    closure()                       // "c is nil"
    print ("<< done")
}                                   // "deinit: changed c"

print ("------------------------------")

if (1==1) {
    print (">> unowned capture clause")
    var d:ValueClass? = ValueClass("d")
    let closure = { [unowned d] in d != nil ? d!.info() : print("d is nil") }
    d = ValueClass("changed d")     // "deinit: d"
    closure()   // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
    print ("<< done")
}
```

The output is

```
>> No capture clause
deinit: a
changed a
<< done
deinit: changed a
------------------------------
>> strong capture clause
b
<< done
deinit: b
deinit: changed b
------------------------------
>> weak capture clause
deinit: c
c is nil
<< done
deinit: changed c
------------------------------
>> unowned capture clause
deinit: d

(CRASH)
```

As you can see,

- when using no capture clause, the value at execution time is used ("changed a")
- when using `[b]`, a strong reference to "b" is created and outputted, since b was "b" at creation time
- when using `[weak c]`, a weak reference to "c" is created; since c has changed to "changed c", the old "c" is deinited, therefore the capture is nilled and the output is "c is nil"
- same when using `[unowned c]`, except that your program crashes